# Place a badge over action bar items

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I have an application with an action bar on the top with two buttons : one on the left (The burger button) that allows to open the left navigation drawer, and one on the right, that allows to open the right drawer. My problem is to place a badge over the icon, but I do not know how to get a reference to the left icon to modify it because it's the android default icon and I do not know how to add the badge. Any suggestion? Thanks in advance

Comment: Might be me, what do you mean with "badge" ?

Comment: Red circle that disappears on touch, like a notification badge

Answer (score 0):

You could always create your own view for the action bar. That way you can not only customize the images you want, but do much more if you wish.

Use `setCustomView()` in the `ActionBar` class to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I did implement this with a helper `Badge` class a while ago. It depends on Dave Smith's [textdrawable](https://github.com/devunwired/textdrawable) library to draw text inside badge. Place `TextDrawable` class near `Badge` class. How to use:

```
Drawable icon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
Badge badge = new Badge(context);
badge.setText("99+");
badge.setBadgeColor(Color.YELLOW);
badge.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
badge.setTextSize(10);
badge.setBadgePosition(Badge.Position.TOP_RIGHT);
badge.setBadgeMargin(10, 10, 10, 10);
badge.setBadgePadding(0, 15, 15, 0);
badge.setBadgeShape(new OvalShape());
badge.enableBorder();
badge.setBorderWidth(4);
badge.setBorderColor(Color.BLACK);
actionBar.setIcon(badge.applyTo(icon));
```

The key idea behind that is to combine given drawable, shape drawable and text drawable in single layer drawable. So badge can be applied to any drawable.

It is available as [gist](https://gist.github.com/kboyarshinov/adcd281c8e7c99c4e556). Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

> how to get a reference to the left icon

You can find the view within the "view tree" of activity. The following codes were verified on nexus5-android5.0, use suopport-v7 actionBar.

```
ViewGroup actionbarView = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.action_bar);
for (int i = 0; i < actionbarView.getChildCount(); i++) {
    // make toggle drawable center-vertical, you can change whatever layoutparameters as you wish
    if (actionbarView.getChildAt(i) instanceof ImageButton) {
        // That is just the left drawer icon, an instance of ImageButton.
        View drawerView = actionbarView.getChildAt(i);
        // add your badge to the View
    }
}
```

It may be different depends on the method you set ActionBar, for example extends ActionBarActivityor or extends just Activity when target android3.0 and above only. You should check your view tree before used.